# How many WFS-T clients exist?

Tags: wfs, wfs-t, ogc, standards

I would like to know which applications or libraries (proprietary or open source) offer transactional Web Feature Service (WFS-T) client functionality. Those include:

- Desktop or online applications that offer the functionality "out of the box", or
- Libraries that can be used to develop a WFS-T client, like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html).

Comment: There probably won't be a single correct answer, so I'm turning the question into a community wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Desktop GIS**

- Opensource: udig, QGIS (Releases currently only supports WFS, developer version contains experimental WFS-T support check [the QGIS bug tracker](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/1583).)
- Commercial: Mapinfo Professional

**Web GIS**

- Opensource: OpenLayers, Mapbuilder & Mapbender
- Commercial: Internet Mapping Framework (IMF)

Most information taken from [geoserver.org](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/Clients).

Comment: As of 2017, qGIS WFS-T support appears to be pretty buggy.

Answer (score 3):

In the ESRI world, WFS-T is supported starting with version 9.3 in [ArcGIS Desktop](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_WFS_support_in_ArcGIS) for visualization of WFS only and [ArcGIS Server](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#tutorial_wfst_service.htm) for publishing and edition through a WFS-T client.

Answer (score 3):

[Gaia](http://www.thecarbonproject.com/gaia.php) a light client with WFS-T functionality

Answer (score 2):

Current development version of QGis suopports WFS-T