# Data entry and manipulation using web pages

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, openlayers-2, geoserver

I am working on a project where we want to move a database from Microsoft Access to PostGIS, and we want the data entry forms to be web page based rather than forms within the Access database.

I am in the process of migrating the database from Access to PostGIS and I have started to use Geoserver, OpenLayers and GeoExt to create maps on pages to look at the data. All this is working fine.

My question is what are the best approaches to allow users to query/edit/enter the attribute and spatial data on the web page? Does anyone have any good links to any tutorials?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into WFS-T "transactional WFS" technology.

> The basic Web Feature Service allows querying and retrieval of features. A transactional Web Feature Service (WFS-T) allows creation, deletion, and updating of features.
>   (Wikipedia)

Check an [example of WFS-T using Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html).

Related questions:

- [How many WFS-T clients exist?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347/how-many-wfs-t-clients-exist)
- [I want to edit corresponding postgresql data of a vector from openlayers- how to do it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/i-want-to-edit-corresponding-postgresql-data-of-a-vector-from-openlayers-how-to)

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I shall check this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have skills in Java, you may want to look at Geomajas. This is a web-mapping framework which allows you to do most stuff on the server side, and have a good interface for the display. All work would be in Java (it uses GWT for the client side). Though it is a young project, it is very mature and functional.