# postgres command to save the line coordinates in openlayers

Tags: open-source-gis, web-mapping, development, geometry

I am working on project that we create one map ant editing toolbar. Then by using that editing tool bar we can draw point, line, polygon on the map. Next we are converting the line, point, polygon objects into coordinates using geometry.toString() function. After that i want to save that coordinates in postgres. I am not able to come out from this dig. If you know the route please let me know. I will follow the steps.

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OpenLayers I'd suggest using Geoserver for handling the connection to Postgis.

Related questions:

- [I want to edit corresponding postgresql data of a vector from openlayers- how to do it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/i-want-to-edit-corresponding-postgresql-data-of-a-vector-from-openlayers-how-to)
- [How many WFS-T clients exist?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347/how-many-wfs-t-clients-exist)

Here is a how the architecture would look like (just with Geoserver in the Middle Tier):

[image]

Comment: k but which function we have to use in postgis?

Comment: You don't use any PostGIS functions directly. Geoserver takes care of it.

Comment: with the advantage that if you decide to switch databases or WFS-T servers later you don't need to change the client. Open Standards - got to love them.