# Recommended way for changing value in PostGIS using GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, wfs, wcs

I have a map being rendered from PostGIS using GeoServer. I frequently make some edits to the map and update the new value by directly connecting to the PostGIS database and then making the changes using SQL query.

Is this the recommended way to do this or does GeoServer offer any other proper way of achieving the same ?

I read slightly about WFS, WCS and WMS and doubt whether they are designed for this task, as I always get lost in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are editing a vectorial layer, you can use WFS-T (WFS Transactional), like this example: [WFS-T with Openlayers](http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html). Or some client with WFS-T support, like QGIS.

This options are more visual, but using SQL query it's perfectly ok for editing.

UPDATE: More info about WFS-T editors [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347/how-many-wfs-t-clients-exist)